# Can I access every byte of a int variable through a char* pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

I was  wondering if I could use a char* value to access to each byte of an int value... So I tried to use a pointer value to access the first byte of the int and a for cycle to access the other bytes of int...
Here's the code:

```
int char_to_bin(char* d){
    int p= (int)*d;
    int i=0,number=0;
    if (p>=0){
        do{

            number+= (p%2)*(pow(10,i));
            i++;
            p= p/2;
            }while (p>0);
        }
    else{
        p=p *(-1);
        do{

            number+= (p%2)*pow(10,i);
            i++;
            p=p/2;
            }while (p>0);
        number*=-1;
        }

    return number;
}

long int int_to_bin(int* p){
    long int j=1,number=0,number1=0,number2=0,digits;
    char* c=&p;
    number=char_to_bin(c);
    for (j;j<(sizeof(int)/sizeof(char));j++){
        number1=char_to_bin(c+j);
        digits=floor(log10(abs(number1))) + 1;
        number2=number1*pow(10,digits);
        number=number1+number2;
    }
    return number;
}


int main(){

    char k= 100;
    char* j= &k;
    int inte=100;
    int *h;
    h= &inte;
    int c= char_to_bin(j);
    printf("%d\n",c);
    long int d= int_to_bin(h);
    printf("%ld\n",d);
}
```

the function `int char_to_bin(char* d)` converts a pointed char value to a binary number, and all the tests I've done on it show it works. But as I use `int char_to_bin(char* d)` in `int_to_bin(int* p)` something goes wrong.
Basically, `int_to_bin(int* p)` should convert the first byte of the pointed int in binary, and then convert the following bytes (since char* points at one only byte) to decimal, multiply the bytes for 10^(number of digits), so that I might get a number like "000000001100100" for example but something goes wrong and the result of the function is far different from binary, plus, i have tried to put a `printf("%d \n",number1)` in the `int_to_bin(int* p)` function, like this:

```
long int int_to_bin(int* p){
    long int j=1,number=0,number1=0,number2=0,digits;
    char* c=&p;
    number=char_to_bin(c);
    for (j;j<(sizeof(int)/sizeof(char));j++){
        number1=char_to_bin(c+j);
        printf("%d \n",number1); //---------------here------------------
        digits=floor(log10(abs(number1))) + 1;
        number2=number1*pow(10,digits);
        number=number1+number2;
    }
    return number;
}
```

to check the value contained in the given memory address... As far as I know, int variable types occupy 4 bytes of memory, and the sum of the content of the bytes is the value or the variable... But I get results that summed are totally different from the variable value.
Is there anything to be done to fix this, or should I just give up and try to convert the int passed `int_to_bin(int* p)` into char and pass it to the `char_to_bin(char* p)` function?

Comment: Probably the 'int' you're talking about is an 'unsigned int' or 'uint32'.  Also, you probably ought to do this by masking the 'uint32' by doing something like 'unsigned char hi_byte = myUint32 & 0xFF00' and 'unsigned char lo_byte = myUint32 & 0x00FF'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As far as I know, int variable types occupy 4 bytes of memory, and the
>   sum of the content of the bytes is the value or the variable...

Well, `int` is `sizeof(int)` bytes, which is *usually* 4 on modern PC operating systems (both 64 and 32 bit), but it can be anything as long as `sizeof(short)` <= `sizeof(int)` <= `sizeof(long)`. So always use `sizeof` instead of hard-coded value.

But value is not *sum* of contents... That would be very wasteful, same bytes in different order would give same int. Value is, depending on byte order, and assuming unsigned numbers:

```
(c[0] << 24) | (c[1] << 16) | (c[2] << 8) | (c[3] << 0); // big endian
```

or

```
(c[3] << 24) | (c[2] << 16) | (c[1] << 8) | (c[0] << 0); // little endian
```

where `unsigned char *c = (unsigned char*)(&unsigned_int_variable);`.

---

Note that even though `char*` pointers are exception (see comments), generally setting pointers of different types to point to values breaks so called ["strict aliasing rules"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule), which you should read about before doing this kind of thing.

Comment: `char *` is an exception to the strict aliasing rule (to allow things like `memcpy` to be implemented).  But otherwise this is correct.

Comment: @TavianBarnes Updated answer about `char*` aliasing, but related to that, `memcpy` takes `void*` so what does `char*` have to do with it?

Comment: `memcpy` could be implemented internally by casting the pointers to `char *` and copying `char`s.  Types other than `char` there would violate strict aliasing.

Comment: @TavianBarnes I updated the answer a bit about strict aliasing, can you give a 2nd opinion about it being correct?

Comment: You're correct about the char rule being "one way", but from my reading of the standard it doesn't apply here.  If you had a `char` array and you accessed it through an `int*` then there would be a problem though.

Comment: @TavianBarnes Mmmyep, rolled back after actual testing (gcc -O2)... `char*` seems to be safe both ways and worked correctly, while other pointer types aliased produced wrong output, and so did `char*` when using `restrict` keyword.